# Angular 1.5 component ...ng-link Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-1.5, angular-component-router

I have nav bar 
**`Home Accounts Services Orders Tickets`**  on click of **Accounts** there is drop-down with fields **new Customer** and **Search Customer** On click of **new Customer** it should navigate to home component.

view of root component:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="tab_ico fa fa-user"></span>
        <span class="tab_name">ACCOUNTS</span>
        <span class="caret_holder"><span class="caret"></span></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="tab_ico fa fa-search"></span> Search customer</a></li>
        <li><a ng-link="['Home']"><span class="tab_ico fa fa-user"></span> New customer</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see ng-link="['Home']"

**routeConfig:**

```
$routeConfig: [  
    { path: "/dashboard", component: "dashboard",name:"Dashboard",useAsDefault: true },  
    { path: "/home", component: "home", name:"Home" },  
    { path: "/account", component: "account", name:"Account" },  
    { path: "/**", redirectTo: ["Home"] }  
],
```

**Home Component**

```
angular.module('app.home').component("home", {
    templateUrl: "app/components/home/homeview.html",

    controllerAs: "model",
    controller: function($scope, dataservice) {
        var vm = this;
        console.log("entered into home component");

    }
})
```

**Home component view**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><span class="tab_ico fa fa-search"></span> SEARCH CUSTOMER <span class="closetab">x</span></li>
        <li class="k-state-active"><span class="tab_ico fa fa-user"></span> Identification <span class="closetab">x</span></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

On click of **new Customer** it should display home component view, But it is not displaying home component view ?, no errors also.!!

Comment: Why you are not using `ngHref` instead of `ngLink`?

Comment: I think both will work same

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngLink` with an `<a>` element without `href`.

Instead of

```
<a href="#" ng-link="['Home']"><span class="tab_ico fa fa-user"></span> New customer</a>
```

Use this

```
<a ng-link="['Home']"><span class="tab_ico fa fa-user"></span> New customer</a>
```

I think that `href` can be the problem here.

**Source**: [Angular Router docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router)

Comment: I have removed href="#" then also same .... its not showing any thing, on click of new customer